# EGit hook read time out

Tags: git, eclipse-plugin, egit

I am using a post-update hook to update the content of my wwwroot with rsync.

The problem that I have is that the sync progress takes some time. Everytime I push my repo I receive a "Read time out" exception in EGit (Eclipse).

Is it possible to increase the timeout or do something else to get the output correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any timeout setting regarding Egit, so I would rather render the process asynchronous, through some kind of [daemon process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29).

In other word, rather than making a (potentially long) `rsync`, I would create a specific file.
A separate process would monitor that file, and when it exists, would trigger the `rsync`, and then erase that file.